# canvas not working properly on IoS mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

Anyone here experience this kind of issue? for some reason, canvas arc() doesn't work on Iphone but works perfectly well on Android. Is there a browser support issue or Am i just missing something?

````
    width = Math.max(elem.offsetParent.offsetWidth),
    height = Math.max(elem.offsetParent.clientHeight);
var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement,
    docWidth = Math.max(body.scrollWidth, body.offsetWidth, html.clientWidth, html.scrollWidth, html.offsetWidth),
    docHeight = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);


var ct = document.getElementById("cv");
var ctx = ct.getContext('2d');   
ct.width = docWidth; 
ct.height = docHeight;

//ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(234, 70, 195 , 0.7)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(width - elem.offsetWidth - 5, docHeight - height + elem.offsetTop + 25, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.rect(width, 0,-docWidth, docHeight);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();```
````

Answer (score 2):

Because `document.documentElement` are not fully supported by Safari IOS.
you can check it on Browser compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement.
And I recommend check the `width-elem.offsetWidth - 5, docHeight - height + elem.offsetTop` ,to make sure these variables are all available.

Do you mean the following effect?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(234, 70, 195 , 0.7)";
ctx.rect(0, 0,100, 100);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.arc(50,50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: The positioning are working properly but for some reason, the fillStyle or fill() are not working, my expected output is that there will be a circle inside the rectangle which is not affected by the fill() and shows the elements behind it.

Comment: Could you show expectation image and current image?